# How to treat the combinatorial part in the expression for $\lim_{x \to y} \frac{x^{n}-y^{n}}{x-y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

My question is somewhat simple I think, I just want to know to treat the combinatorial part in the expression for $$\lim_{x \to y} \frac{x^{n}-y^{n}}{x-y}$$.

What I mean by this is I know how to solve this question but I was attempting to do it with another notation. So normally what transpires is the following:

$$\lim_{x \to y} \frac{x^{n}-y^{n}}{x-y} \\ = \lim_{x \to y} \frac{(x-y)(x^{n-1}+yx^{n-2}+ \dots y^{n-1})}{x-y} = ny^{n-1}$$

But I was attempting to express the larger polynomial as $$(x^{n-1}+yx^{n-2}+ \dots y^{n-1})= (x+y)^{n-1} = \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{m}x^{(n-1)-m} y^{m}$$.

Doing this I run into problems with the combinatorial expression for the coefficients. How would I remedy this? I know I was probably trying to be too clever for my own good, but compact notation is what is desired at a higher level so I may as well get practice in now.

Comment: $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$ but $(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$. Your expression for $(x + y)^{n -1}$ is correct, but $(x+y)^{n-1}$ isn't the right object for this problem.

Comment: The coefficients are all $1s$... $$x^{n-1} + \cdots + y^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-k-1} y^{k}$$ you could not ask for a more compact notation if you tried.

Comment: But $x^{n-1}+yx^{n-2}+\cdots+y^n$ **isn't** $(x+y)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, funny enough it was a difference of cubes that I was basing my expression off of and now looking back at that expression I actually factored it wrong. Thanks for the clarification. Do you want to put it in an answer so I can mark close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting my comment as an answer.

Note that
$$
(x + y)^{n-1} = x^{n-1} + (n-1)x^{n-2} y + \ldots + y^{n-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k} x^{(n-1) - k} y ^k
$$
But
$$
x^n - y^n = (x - y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3} y + \ldots + y^{n-1}) = (x-y) \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} x^{(n-1) - k} y^k \right)
$$

Comment: Your coefficients are off. $x^{n-2}y$ has coefficient n-2, the next term also has a mistake in its coefficient.

Comment: You're right. I'll fix it. So strange. I wonder what I was thinking of